# Using bridges and pluggable transports with Tallow

Tags: configuration, pluggable-transports

I am trying to use Tallow to circumvent blocking on the wifi network I am using. However, TOR is blocked, so a bridge is needed. The TOR browser works with the meek-amazon setting, but how do I edit the Tallow torrc file to work in the same way?

All the info I have found is for the TOR browser. Can anyone help?

Comment: Tallow isn't developed, supported or recommended by the Tor Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define 3 things in your `torrc` configuration file:

1. `ClientTransportPlugin` to give Tor a name and a path to an executable to act as the pluggable transport. You can find the pluggable transport executables in the Tor Browser package. It takes the form `ClientTransportPlugin transport exec path-to-binary [options]`

e.g. `ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 C:\Users\user\obfs4proxy.exe`

2. `UseBridges` to tell Tor to use bridges. It takes the form `UseBridges 0|1`

e.g. `UseBridges 1`

3. `Bridge` lines that define the bridge to use and the pluggable transport. It takes the form `Bridge [transport] IP:ORPort [fingerprint]`.

e.g. `Bridge obfs4 1.2.3.4:56789 0123456789ABCDEF cert=tMrWpcHsn7buAAS4USGKxKyKEFv9t3HmzfDZ1cLYB0o= iat-mode=0`

Comment: obfs4 `exec` command is necessary; otherwise, everything works as expected; the list of bridges can be copied from Tor Browser settings ('request new bridges'); the obfs4 executable can be copied directly to Tallow folder to get rid of 'Strange...' error